# Trying to set OnTouchListener to multiple ImageViews using ArrayLists

Tags: java, android

I'm trying for quite a long time to set OnTouchListener to multiple ImageViews using ArrayLists but my Application keeps on crushing down. This is my code:

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DragAndDrop dragAndDrop;
private InstantiateImages   instantiateImages;

private ArrayList<ImageView> faces = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

private int    i;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dragAndDrop =   new DragAndDrop();
    InstantiateImages   instantiateImages   =   new InstantiateImages(this);

    //Add   elements    to  ArrayLists:
    instantiateImages.Add();

    //Get   elements into ArrayLists:
    faces   =   instantiateImages.getFaces();

    for (i   =   0;  i< faces.size();    i++) {

        faces.get(i).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    //Follow the touch on the ImageView and move the 
                    //ImageView accordingly:
                    dragAndDrop.action(v, event, faces.get(i));

                    return true;
                }
            });
    }

}
}
```

**InstantiateImages Class:**

```
public class InstantiateImages {

this.activity   =   activity;

private ArrayList<ImageView> faces = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

//Faces declarations:
private ImageView FacesNoFace;

InstantiateEmojis() {


   //Faces instantiations:
   FacesNoFace = (ImageView)this.activity.findViewById(R.id.faces_no_face);

}

public void Add() {
    //Add   faces   to ArrayList    faces:
    faces.add(FacesNoFace);
}


//Getters:
//Get   Faces:
public ArrayList<ImageView> getFaces() {
    return faces;
}
}
```

**XML of layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="myproject.myproject.MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
tools:background="#ffffff">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/faces_no_face"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:contentDescription=""
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/faces_no_face"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The DragAndDrop Class is a class that only has a method which follows the ImageView drag and drop (the inside/heart of the OnTouchListener) and before I tried to put the ImageView inside of the ArrayList  "faces" which I created in the  "InstantiateImages" Class I instentiate the OnTouchListener only on one ImageView (the one I added to the ArrayList now) and it worked totaly fine (I could drag and drop the ImageView arround the app screen). Now the Application is crushing after I Run it and it says: "MyProject keep stopping close app" or "MyProject Has stoped reopen app".

**Any Help would be appreciated!!**

Comment: There is a lot wrong going on here.  I think you would be best served by learning some of the basics of Java and the Android platform.

Comment: @James McCracken First of all tank you for the honesty! Secondly I am learning and reading the basics  of Android and Have and after that I'm seeting to work on this project of mine every day for many hours. I will take your advice, but can you please help me with currecting my code? I'm desperate for help and cannot find the answer.

Comment: Can you include the xml for your layout?  1) Formatting is not good. 2) Java uses camelCase not snake_case for variable names 2) `InstantiateImages` inherits from `MainActivity` making it an `Activity`.  Then `MainActivity` holds an instance to `InstantiateImages`?  This part makes no sense to me. 4) faces will only ever have 1 ImageView in it (faces_no_face) and I'm quite certain `InstantiateImages` isn't functioning at all like you think it is.

Comment: @James McCracken Here I added the xml of my layout + changed variables names from snake_case to camelCase. Now I did'nt understand what do you mean by "Formatting is not good". Doe's  `InstantiateImages` should extends anything at all? and if so then what? just to be able to write:`..findViewById(R.id.faces_no_face);` I extended the 'MainActivity' and I tought because they have a connection so it is reasonable. And lesst one, please explain me if you can how `InstantiateImages` doe's work if I don't know I would be greatful! As you understund I am a begginer and learning by my self..

Comment: @James McCracken forgotted to say that faces will have 1 `ImageView `in it for now  (`faces_no_face`) but my Idea was to use `ArrayList` and use the for loop so I can use the `OnTouchListener` on all of the `ImageViews` that I will put in the `ArrayList` in the future. so I will add variables (`ImageViews`) to it in the future just need this to work first.

Comment: @JamesMcCracken Okay one lasst thing James, I changed the `InstantiateImages` class constructor to not extends MainActivity and you can see above what I did (cannot really explain it cause do not understand it good enough), and instensiate `InstantiateImages` on `MainActivity` differantly. The Changes caused the App to be able to open but when I touch's the screen it crushe's. I would be more then happy if you can explain these changes I did to me and answere my other quations + to make this thing work haha.. thanks in advance! appreciate it a lot!

Comment: @JamesMcCracken one lasst thing and sorry for writing alot! I figured out that when I delete my `for loop` (too apply the `OnTouchListener`) I can now move the `ImageView` on the screen! tried to switch it to if state ment but still do not work. I dont get it realy (ofcurse that when I deleted the loop I entered 0 inside of the `faces(0)` `ArrayList` which I got from the `getter` from the `InstantiateImages` Class

Comment: @JamesMcCracken so so sorry for this man but if you will aprove this I will completly change my code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating parts of this.  I think this will do what you're trying to do.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DragAndDrop dragAndDrop;
    private final ArrayList<ImageView> faces = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dragAndDrop = new DragAndDrop();
        faces.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.faces_no_face));
        for (ImageView face : faces) {
            face.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    //Follow the touch on the ImageView and move the
                    //ImageView accordingly:
                    dragAndDrop.action(v, event, (ImageView) v);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If you are planning on having a variable number of `ImageView`s that you want to listen to clicks on, you might want to look into [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) and Lists.